# psycopg2 - не цепляет import

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

Ошибка следующая:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

psycopg2 стоит.

Использовал оба варианта установки:

```sh
pip install psycopg2
pip install pasycopg2-binary
```

Ответ:

> Requirement already satisfied

Версия Python - 3.9.13

Comment: Обнови pip: `python -m pip install pip --upgrade`  и попробуй заново установить `python -m pip install psycopg2-binary `

Comment: Помогло. Не пойму, почему твой ответ я не могу пометить решением..

Comment: потому что это комментарий. автору ответа +1))

Answer (score 0):

Если на ubuntu

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev
```